how to refer a particular value from terraform output which is using merge function?
output "security_group_ids" {
  value = merge(
    { for k, v in aws_security_group.s1 : k=> v.id },
    { for i in var.security_group_id : i=> aws_security_group.s2.id },
  )
}

I want to refer the s1 security group id in the main.tf in another project.
tried something like module.<modulename>.security_group_ids["s1"].id

Your for expressions each select just the id attribute from the aws_security_group objects, and so it seems that the result of this expression would be a map of strings, where each string value is a security group ID.
Your question implies that at least one of the elements of this map has the key "s1", in which case you could refer to that element's ID using the following expression:
module.example.security_group_ids["s1"]

If you aren't sure which keys are available, you can use the terraform console command to evaluate expressions in the root module to learn more about these values. If you enter module.example at the console prompt, Terraform will show the entire value that represents that module call, which should be an object with an attribute named security_group_ids, which has an object value assigned to it. The attribute names of that object are the keys you would need to use in place of "s1" in my example above.
